# Books for field theory

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, resource-recommendations, field-theory

I am a math student, studying P.D.E. of some EM theory.

I am new to field theory and I don't even know what a Lagrangian density, Hamiltonian density, or gauge field theory is.

Could you please introduce some books or notes to me?

Comment: One of the standard textbooks to learn analytical mechanics and field theory from scratch is http://www.amazon.de/Classical-Mechanics-Herbert-Goldstein/dp/0321188977. Another book that I really liked is http://www.amazon.com/Lectures-Analytical-Mechanics-F-Gantmacher/dp/B000LZJN3E. These two introduce classical analytical mechanics, from which you can start to approach general field theories.